# Flutter constructor error on android studio. It keeps showing error

Tags: android, flutter, class, dart, constructor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqVxj.png)
When I try to create a new class in the library of flutter, inside the class the constructor shows error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Also, please copy-paste the problematic code between ``` instead of an image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have your parameters as optionally named, which means the caller can decide not to pass `q` or `a`, but you also marked them as non-nullable. Add the `required` keyword before your parameters to make sure they're passed in and are non-null, or add a default.

Also, in the future:

- Please copy-paste your code instead of using an image. This lets us quickly copy-paste it into our IDEs and find any errors.
- Please post the error you're getting. Errors are your friends, they tell you what's wrong, and they'll help us figure out how to help you.